# add comment in membership

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I want to add comment in the membership table.
I added this in my .aspx code:

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="Register" runat="server"  OnCreatedUser="RegisterUserWithRoles_CreatedUser">
        <CreateUserButtonStyle />
        <WizardSteps>
            <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate> 
<table>
<td align="right">
                                <asp:Label ID="RoomLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Room">Room number:</asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Room" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RoomRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Room"
                                    ErrorMessage="Room number is required." ToolTip="Room number is required."
                                    ValidationGroup="Register">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>

...
```

This is my aspx.cs code:

```
 protected void RegisterUserWithRoles_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox comment=
              (TextBox)CreateUserWizardStep1.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Comment");
            Membership.GetUser(Register.UserName).Comment = comment.Text ;
        }
    }
```

If I debug comment.Text= "What I typ in my textbox"
But if I look in the membership table comment is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must just use UpdateUser.
Like this:

```
TextBox comment=
              (TextBox)CreateUserWizardStep1.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Comment");
            MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(Register.UserName);
            user.Comment = comment.Text; 
            Membership.UpdateUser(user);
```